# Proof about continuous function

Tags: analysis

I try to prove this but I can not do it. Please give me some hint or help, thank you.

> Suppose $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f(a)<0.$
> Then exists $r>0$ such that $f(x)<0$ for all $x \in [a,a+r]\cap \operatorname{Dom} f$.

Comment: What's the question...? I don't understand it.

Comment: @an4s. I suppose that the question is how to show then "Then exists ..." statement.

Comment: It suffices that $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: @EstebanLS Can you give the definition of the continuity of $f$ at the point $x=a$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon=-\frac12 f(a).$ Since $f$ is continuous at $a$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta.$ But then, for $x\in[a,a+\delta),$
$$
f(a)-\epsilon < f(x) < f(a)+\epsilon,
$$
i.e., using only the second inequality,
$$
f(x) < f(a) + \left(-\frac12 f(a)\right) = \frac12 f(a) < 0.
$$
Now take $r=\frac12\delta.$ It is clear that $f(x)<0$ when $x\in[a,a+r]$.

Answer (score -1):

Take $$\epsilon = \dfrac{-f(a)}{2} > 0$$ then there is a delta $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in [a,a+\delta)$ we have: $$|f(x) - f(a)| < -\dfrac{f(a)}{2}\implies f(x) - f(a) < -\dfrac{f(a)}{2} \implies f(x) < f(a) - \dfrac{f(a)}{2} = \dfrac{f(a)}{2} < 0$$ Thus $r = \delta$.

Answer (score -1):

Case 1: $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in \text{Dom}(f)$, then take $r = b-a$

Case 2: There exists $x \in \text{Dom}(f)$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$, then use the intermediate value theorem to find $r$

Comment: IVT is really an overkill here, since it is sufficient that $f$ is continuous at $a$, and not necessarily on the whole interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe so what can I do to make the proof better?

Comment: I am not saying that your proof (or hint, rather) is incorrect, but just that you don't need the IVT. But if you want to make a full answer, I suggest that you develop it and write in details the proof you have in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $f$ is continuous at $x=a$ and apply [definition of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_and_Jordan_definitions_(epsilon%E2%80%93delta)_of_continuous_functions)  of $f$ at $x=a$.